# export csv file from magento 1.9 to import product csv in magento 2.3.0

Tags: csv, magento2.3.0, import-products

I have a task to import products from m1 to m2.

I having the CSV file with products(from Magento 1 export) at the moment. When I try to "Check Data" on the import page - is always loading.

How can I import products from m1 to m2 via CSV file or another approach except for data-migration-tool?

**P.S magento 1 -  1.9.3.1, magento 2 - 2.3.0**

Comment: you just have to export all the product from magento1 and make this export csv format to magento2 format and import it in magento2

Answer (score 0):

The databases of Magento 1 and 2 are not formated the same always.

So you can't directly import between the two generally.

Though what you can do is to restructure the info so it fits the scheme of the Magneto 2 databases. There's a lot of rows that might need to change and some info that might have to be added.

There are samples that you can get so you can see how the Magento 2 imports CSV. files should be formatted. They are located in the admin panel at System->Import if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Consider trying tests with just a couple of products. If Magento 2.x seems to be loading the file indefinitely without validating for errors, it could be a result of having a large number of products and insufficient server resources.

I would recommend initially creating the products via CSV, using the minimum required fields, and then proceed to import their various attributes.